# Why doesn't @UiThreadTest work?

Tags: android

Why does this code:

```
public class SomeTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    @UiThreadTest
    public void testSubscribe_noErrorHandler_threadingCorrect() throws Throwable {
        android.util.Log.i("Now@" + Thread.currentThread().currentThread().getId());
        runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               android.util.Log.i("Later@" + Thread.currentThread().currentThread().getId());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

..produce this output:

```
09-11 15:20:10.783    5155-5170/com.agens.android.vgsnarvei I/﹕ Now@2018
09-11 15:20:10.783    5155-5155/com.agens.android.vgsnarvei I/﹕ Later@1
```

I expected  `Now@1`, `Later@1`, given that the documentation of `@UiThreadTest` claims it's supposes to run on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

See this [UiThreadTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/UiThreadTestRule.html)

post answer about this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35803978/3213789